# I need to make Messenger chatbot communicate with other script on server

Tags: facebook, heroku, chatbot, messenger

I'm new in this all chatbot hipe and I need a little help.
I have simple chatbot "echo" running on Heroku, and I want to make that bot communicate with other script. 
So, I want to pass some info (string, link, image...) to chatbot from another script on Heroku server.
I have some Python script that generate images on server so I want to make chatbot "pick" right image and pass to user as answer.

For example:
- User type "fruit"
- Chatbot pass that keyword to Python script.
- PY generate image fruit.jpg (download from google, from some server... not important right now)
- Chatbot pick that image and send to user.

Important thing is that I no need static URL, I need to make all it dynamic so every user get image for their request - keyword.

```
  "message":{
    "attachment":{
      "type":"image",
      "payload":{
        "url":"https://petersapparel.com/img/shirt.png"
      }
    }
  }
```

You see "url":"https://..."
That is static URL, I need variable there. I can't do that with switch, IF etc. because I don't know what keyword user will send.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Of course it’s “possible.” But this question is way to vague and broad for a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Node.js, you can simply try something like this :

```
"url":"https://petersapparel.com/img/"+keyword+".png"
```

On your server, you can set up an .htaccess to do URL Rewriting and convert `https://petersapparel.com/img/shirt.png` to `https://petersapparel.com/img/script.py?keyword=shirt`